# Can't print string custom kernel operating system

Tags: string, gcc, assembly, x86, kernel

So, I'm learning about kernels, assembly, etc., following the 32-bit kernel tutorial on github from cfenollosa. I  got to lesson 16 and now I'm having a problem with printing a string onto the qemu emulator. It seems to place a single asteriks no matter what the string is. It does display the asteriks where the string should start. Also when clearing the screen, I get a little green box at the top. Anybody familiar with this tutorial series? I have my current files uploaded on jumpshare at this link https://jumpshare.com/b/5KWAyzNTEQLul3hMGvpj

I'm using qemu, and nasm on my 64-bit linux (arch linux) as my programming computer, as well as the gcc compiler. I skipped the cross compiler lessons, so I don't have any cross-compiler functionality. Since this is my only pc, it seemed irrelevant at the time. I'm really clueless as to why this is happening. I keep looking over my code and can't find anything.

Comment: Please include the relevant bits in the question itself rather than linking to it.

Comment: The irrelevant part is likely the cause of your issue. Are you on a 64-bit Linux system by any chance? I'm going to guess from your Makefile that you are.Looking at your bootloader it puts the machine in 32-bit protected mode but you are trying to run code you compiled/assembled for 64-bit code. That doesn't work. You'll either need a i686(or i386) cross compiler or you will have to modify your Makefile to generate 32-bit code specifying on the compiler (GCC) command line `-m32` (maybe even `-fno-PIE`) on your linker (ld) line add `-melf_i386` and NASM used `-felf32` instead of `-felf64`

Comment: One of the first side effects people who make this mistake experience is often that the video output is not as expected.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am using a 64-bit linux system. I didn't realize that not using a cross-compiler had something to do with these problems. It does make sense. I'm definitely going to check it out.

Comment: Your Linux system by default is generating 64-bit code unless you override the command line parameters to have your compiler/linker/assembler generate 32-bit code. This can still be problematic as the host environment (64-bit Linux) may be using default options that don't work well with 32-bit OS development. Using a cross compiler can definitely alleviate those problems.